# cx_Oracle Package Not working inside Crontab

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, cron, cx-oracle

I am using cx_Oracle library in my python script. My code works fine if I directly execute by python script from Linux terminal but when I put it in crontab I am getting following error.

!!DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html for help

DPI-1005: unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
!!Traceback (most recent call last):
import cx_Oracle
!!DatabaseError: DPI-1005: unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

I googled this issue and It seems some environment variable missing when it ran using crontab.
I try to export following in crontab but it does not work.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib'

If I remove cx_Oracle package other code runs fine. I have only one version of python installed on my machine.

What is your version of Python? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?
Python 2.6 . 64 bit

What is your version of cx_Oracle?
Version 6.0b1

What is your version of the Oracle client (e.g. Instant Client)? How was it
installed? Where is it installed?
oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm

What is your OS and version?
CentOS 6.7

What environment variables did you set? How exactly did you set them?
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib'

Answer (score 1):

Evidently cron doesn't load the bash profile so you will need write a wrapper.

So, write a bash wrapper that exports the variables needed and calls the script. Then call that wrapper from crontab. When that works, you will know that your variables weren't being properly exported for the user whose crontab you edited.

Note: You can add them into `/etc/bashrc` and it will then be in place for all users, if you have root access.

You can also make a generic wrapper and cron things be sending them through the wrapper.

**my_bash_wrapper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.bash_profile
"$0"
```

**evoke in cron:**

```
0 1 * * * /my/loc/my_bash_wrapper.sh my_python_script arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working since its looking for the oracle instant client path.
In the shell script, add the export line and point it to your oracle client path. Next, keep writing your shell script. This will work!

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<user_name>/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/anaconda3/bin/python /home/<user_name>/test/src/test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client(64)
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work for some user
I am using Gnome Schedular to schedule python scipts.

**For Normal jobs.**

> ~anaconda3/bin/python /path_to_script/target_script.py

**For Job which needs environement variable.**

> . ~/bash_profile ~anaconda3/bin/python /path_to_script/target_script.py