# Connection to Oracle db (cx_Oracle) not working when scheduled from crontab but works as standalone

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, cron, cx-oracle

I have a python (3.6) script that does some things with data retrieved from Oracle DB.
Then I have a shell script for automation that execute the script. I than schedule the execution of such shell in **crontab**.

**If I execute the shell as standalone (sh shell.sh) it works perfectly fine, while when it runs as a crontab job connection to Oracle DB fails --> *class 'cx_Oracle.DatabaseError'***

I'm trying to simplify the code I'm using, the **Python script** is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# coding: utf-8
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(username/pwd@hostname:port/db_name)
    query = """SELECT * FROM schema.table"""
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con = conn)
except:
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
    sys.exit(1)
```

The **shell** is doing something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [something]
then
    python3.6 pyscript.py
fi
```

The **crontab -l** result:

```
* * * * * cd /root/workindirectory ; sudo sh shell.sh >> test.out
```

**Thank you** all in advance for any help.

EDIT: to specify that both shell and python scripts have 777 permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry as I think this was a duplicate of [cx_Oracle Package Not working inside Crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794503/cx-oracle-package-not-working-inside-crontab)

As cron does not load bash profile, I've found a solution exporting ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the shell script. As pointed out in the linked question, the lines to be added are:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client(64)
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```